# DB queries slower after upgrading from MySQL 5.6 into Maria DB 10.2

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb, query-optimization

I wanted to improve my queries speed. as far as I know, queries were pretty optimized, and used INNODB tables.

I was suggested to upgrade from MySQL 5.6 into Maria DB 10.2.

I was expecting queries to be at least slighlty faster, but all queries seem to be either slower or slightly slower than before.

Nothing has changed in the DB, not its size, not the queries, and as far I as can tell neither the structure. Buffer size seems ok, still having free space.
I also tried running OPTIMIZE TABLE command.

What I'm having is about 2 different view tables that makes some joins of core tables. both became slower, as query takes longer to run. also frontend interface that is reading from them is now loading slower.

The only thing I was told is that since I made the upgrade about 7 hours ago, I should wait 24 hours for the DB to gain statistics, and then my host can run MySQL Tuner to try and optimize things. but I really doubt these tweaks could offer any help.

The only good thing about the upgrade is that MariaDB takes 40% of CPU power, instead of MYSQL that took 90% power (having 4 cores).

I'm thinking about doing a complete VPS restore into My SQL 5.6 again, and then maybe trying upgrade to 5.7 instead and see if it somehow helps.
I'm not very keen to do this since I might lose some data.

Can you offer me a checklist to see why MariaDB is slower? I had high hopes for it.

SHOW GLOBAL VALUES:

```
Variable_name   Value
Aborted_clients 299
Aborted_connects    478
Access_denied_errors    504
Acl_column_grants   2
Acl_database_grants 628
Acl_function_grants 0
Acl_procedure_grants    0
Acl_proxy_users 0
Acl_role_grants 0
Acl_roles   0
Acl_table_grants    4
Acl_users   575
Aria_pagecache_blocks_not_flushed   0
Aria_pagecache_blocks_unused    15706
Aria_pagecache_blocks_used  15706
Aria_pagecache_read_requests    1854966046
Aria_pagecache_reads    2710380
Aria_pagecache_write_requests   203175791
Aria_pagecache_writes   265268
Aria_transaction_log_syncs  17
Binlog_commits  0
Binlog_group_commits    0
Binlog_group_commit_trigger_count   0
Binlog_group_commit_trigger_lock_wait   0
Binlog_group_commit_trigger_timeout 0
Binlog_snapshot_file    
Binlog_snapshot_position    0
Binlog_bytes_written    0
Binlog_cache_disk_use   0
Binlog_cache_use    0
Binlog_stmt_cache_disk_use  0
Binlog_stmt_cache_use   0
Busy_time   0.000000
Bytes_received  11320082022
Bytes_sent  10732887549
Com_admin_commands  1
Com_alter_db    0
Com_alter_db_upgrade    0
Com_alter_event 0
Com_alter_function  0
Com_alter_procedure 0
Com_alter_server    0
Com_alter_table 0
Com_alter_tablespace    0
Com_alter_user  0
Com_analyze 0
Com_assign_to_keycache  0
Com_begin   6
Com_binlog  0
Com_call_procedure  1485
Com_change_db   450
Com_change_master   0
Com_check   32
Com_checksum    0
Com_commit  0
Com_compound_sql    0
Com_create_db   0
Com_create_event    0
Com_create_function 0
Com_create_index    0
Com_create_procedure    0
Com_create_role 0
Com_create_server   0
Com_create_table    0
Com_create_temporary_table  0
Com_create_trigger  0
Com_create_udf  0
Com_create_user 0
Com_create_view 5
Com_dealloc_sql 0
Com_delete  843141
Com_delete_multi    0
Com_do  0
Com_drop_db 0
Com_drop_event  0
Com_drop_function   0
Com_drop_index  0
Com_drop_procedure  0
Com_drop_role   0
Com_drop_server 0
Com_drop_table  0
Com_drop_temporary_table    0
Com_drop_trigger    0
Com_drop_user   0
Com_drop_view   0
Com_empty_query 0
Com_execute_immediate   0
Com_execute_sql 0
Com_flush   0
Com_get_diagnostics 0
Com_grant   0
Com_grant_role  0
Com_ha_close    0
Com_ha_open 0
Com_ha_read 0
Com_help    0
Com_insert  7981484
Com_insert_select   253045
Com_install_plugin  0
Com_kill    0
Com_load    0
Com_lock_tables 6
Com_multi   0
Com_optimize    0
Com_preload_keys    0
Com_prepare_sql 0
Com_purge   0
Com_purge_before_date   0
Com_release_savepoint   6
Com_rename_table    0
Com_rename_user 0
Com_repair  0
Com_replace 4
Com_replace_select  0
Com_reset   0
Com_resignal    0
Com_revoke  0
Com_revoke_all  0
Com_revoke_role 0
Com_rollback    0
Com_rollback_to_savepoint   85
Com_savepoint   6
Com_select  11930889
Com_set_option  50894
Com_show_authors    0
Com_show_binlog_events  0
Com_show_binlogs    1
Com_show_charsets   0
Com_show_collations 0
Com_show_contributors   0
Com_show_create_db  6
Com_show_create_event   0
Com_show_create_func    0
Com_show_create_proc    5
Com_show_create_table   300
Com_show_create_trigger 1
Com_show_create_user    0
Com_show_databases  3
Com_show_engine_logs    0
Com_show_engine_mutex   0
Com_show_engine_status  6
Com_show_errors 0
Com_show_events 6
Com_show_explain    0
Com_show_fields 2376
Com_show_function_status    6
Com_show_generic    0
Com_show_grants 134
Com_show_keys   1739
Com_show_master_status  32
Com_show_open_tables    0
Com_show_plugins    11
Com_show_privileges 0
Com_show_procedure_status   6
Com_show_processlist    315
Com_show_profile    0
Com_show_profiles   0
Com_show_relaylog_events    0
Com_show_slave_hosts    1
Com_show_slave_status   33
Com_show_status 323
Com_show_storage_engines    1
Com_show_table_status   6131
Com_show_tables 2396
Com_show_triggers   0
Com_show_variables  714
Com_show_warnings   128
Com_shutdown    0
Com_signal  0
Com_start_all_slaves    0
Com_start_slave 0
Com_stmt_close  0
Com_stmt_execute    0
Com_stmt_fetch  0
Com_stmt_prepare    0
Com_stmt_reprepare  0
Com_stmt_reset  0
Com_stmt_send_long_data 0
Com_stop_all_slaves 0
Com_stop_slave  0
Com_truncate    422
Com_uninstall_plugin    0
Com_unlock_tables   12
Com_update  2573397
Com_update_multi    152
Com_xa_commit   0
Com_xa_end  0
Com_xa_prepare  0
Com_xa_recover  0
Com_xa_rollback 0
Com_xa_start    0
Compression OFF
Connection_errors_accept    0
Connection_errors_internal  0
Connection_errors_max_connections   0
Connection_errors_peer_address  0
Connection_errors_select    0
Connection_errors_tcpwrap   0
Connections 140702
Cpu_time    0.000000
Created_tmp_disk_tables 2418056
Created_tmp_files   106
Created_tmp_tables  2522605
Delayed_errors  0
Delayed_insert_threads  0
Delayed_writes  0
Delete_scan 282726
Empty_queries   2404725
Executed_events 0
Executed_triggers   26
Feature_check_constraint    0
Feature_delay_key_write 0
Feature_dynamic_columns 0
Feature_fulltext    0
Feature_gis 0
Feature_locale  1531
Feature_subquery    2376355
Feature_timezone    119
Feature_trigger 4
Feature_window_functions    0
Feature_xml 0
Flush_commands  1
Handler_commit  20420571
Handler_delete  217546
Handler_discover    52
Handler_external_lock   0
Handler_icp_attempts    16044703
Handler_icp_match   11054717
Handler_mrr_init    0
Handler_mrr_key_refills 0
Handler_mrr_rowid_refills   0
Handler_prepare 0
Handler_read_first  26119
Handler_read_key    1531231725
Handler_read_last   198
Handler_read_next   1184111206
Handler_read_prev   36439635
Handler_read_retry  0
Handler_read_rnd    38946254
Handler_read_rnd_deleted    2229
Handler_read_rnd_next   1178846918
Handler_rollback    6259
Handler_savepoint   6
Handler_savepoint_rollback  85
Handler_tmp_update  475645291
Handler_tmp_write   222281804
Handler_update  4885404
Handler_write   7986165
Innodb_buffer_pool_dump_status  
Innodb_buffer_pool_load_status  Buffer pool(s) load completed at 190125 16:08:08
Innodb_buffer_pool_resize_status    
Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_data   30645
Innodb_buffer_pool_bytes_data   502087680
Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_dirty  284
Innodb_buffer_pool_bytes_dirty  4653056
Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_flushed    3861244
Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_free   1024
Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_misc   1099
Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_total  32768
Innodb_buffer_pool_read_ahead_rnd   0
Innodb_buffer_pool_read_ahead   30275
Innodb_buffer_pool_read_ahead_evicted   1
Innodb_buffer_pool_read_requests    4008810449
Innodb_buffer_pool_reads    44847
Innodb_buffer_pool_wait_free    0
Innodb_buffer_pool_write_requests   70465247
Innodb_data_fsyncs  8780668
Innodb_data_pending_fsyncs  0
Innodb_data_pending_reads   0
Innodb_data_pending_writes  0
Innodb_data_read    1232669184
Innodb_data_reads   75411
Innodb_data_writes  12266582
Innodb_data_written 139210191360
Innodb_dblwr_pages_written  3861113
Innodb_dblwr_writes 163358
Innodb_log_waits    0
Innodb_log_write_requests   10056689
Innodb_log_writes   8205831
Innodb_os_log_fsyncs    8220974
Innodb_os_log_pending_fsyncs    0
Innodb_os_log_pending_writes    0
Innodb_os_log_written   12679490048
Innodb_page_size    16384
Innodb_pages_created    119993
Innodb_pages_read   75231
Innodb_pages0_read  169
Innodb_pages_written    3861244
Innodb_row_lock_current_waits   0
Innodb_row_lock_time    23939
Innodb_row_lock_time_avg    11
Innodb_row_lock_time_max    2717
Innodb_row_lock_waits   2097
Innodb_rows_deleted 214957
Innodb_rows_inserted    5440067
Innodb_rows_read    1339344193
Innodb_rows_updated 2693566
Innodb_system_rows_deleted  0
Innodb_system_rows_inserted 0
Innodb_system_rows_read 0
Innodb_system_rows_updated  0
Innodb_num_open_files   172
Innodb_truncated_status_writes  0
Innodb_available_undo_logs  128
Innodb_undo_truncations 0
Innodb_page_compression_saved   0
Innodb_num_index_pages_written  0
Innodb_num_non_index_pages_written  0
Innodb_num_pages_page_compressed    0
Innodb_num_page_compressed_trim_op  0
Innodb_num_pages_page_decompressed  0
Innodb_num_pages_page_compression_error 0
Innodb_num_pages_encrypted  0
Innodb_num_pages_decrypted  0
Innodb_have_lz4 OFF
Innodb_have_lzo OFF
Innodb_have_lzma    ON
Innodb_have_bzip2   OFF
Innodb_have_snappy  OFF
Innodb_have_punch_hole  ON
Innodb_defragment_compression_failures  0
Innodb_defragment_failures  0
Innodb_defragment_count 0
Innodb_onlineddl_rowlog_rows    0
Innodb_onlineddl_rowlog_pct_used    0
Innodb_onlineddl_pct_progress   0
Innodb_secondary_index_triggered_cluster_reads  588406139
Innodb_secondary_index_triggered_cluster_reads_avoided  0
Innodb_encryption_rotation_pages_read_from_cache    0
Innodb_encryption_rotation_pages_read_from_disk 0
Innodb_encryption_rotation_pages_modified   0
Innodb_encryption_rotation_pages_flushed    0
Innodb_encryption_rotation_estimated_iops   0
Innodb_encryption_key_rotation_list_length  0
Innodb_encryption_n_merge_blocks_encrypted  0
Innodb_encryption_n_merge_blocks_decrypted  0
Innodb_encryption_n_rowlog_blocks_encrypted 0
Innodb_encryption_n_rowlog_blocks_decrypted 0
Innodb_scrub_background_page_reorganizations    0
Innodb_scrub_background_page_splits 0
Innodb_scrub_background_page_split_failures_underflow   0
Innodb_scrub_background_page_split_failures_out_of_filespace    0
Innodb_scrub_background_page_split_failures_missing_index   0
Innodb_scrub_background_page_split_failures_unknown 0
Innodb_scrub_log    0
Innodb_encryption_num_key_requests  0
Key_blocks_not_flushed  0
Key_blocks_unused   10282
Key_blocks_used 3107
Key_blocks_warm 2877
Key_read_requests   666586322
Key_reads   3078
Key_write_requests  261701
Key_writes  258980
Last_query_cost 0.000000
Master_gtid_wait_count  0
Master_gtid_wait_time   0
Master_gtid_wait_timeouts   0
Max_statement_time_exceeded 0
Max_used_connections    44
Memory_used 176589696
Not_flushed_delayed_rows    0
Open_files  277
Open_streams    0
Open_table_definitions  400
Open_tables 951
Opened_files    9677372
Opened_plugin_libraries 0
Opened_table_definitions    1043
Opened_tables   1436
Opened_views    421537
Performance_schema_accounts_lost    0
Performance_schema_cond_classes_lost    0
Performance_schema_cond_instances_lost  0
Performance_schema_digest_lost  0
Performance_schema_file_classes_lost    0
Performance_schema_file_handles_lost    0
Performance_schema_file_instances_lost  0
Performance_schema_hosts_lost   0
Performance_schema_locker_lost  0
Performance_schema_mutex_classes_lost   0
Performance_schema_mutex_instances_lost 0
Performance_schema_rwlock_classes_lost  0
Performance_schema_rwlock_instances_lost    0
Performance_schema_session_connect_attrs_lost   0
Performance_schema_socket_classes_lost  0
Performance_schema_socket_instances_lost    0
Performance_schema_stage_classes_lost   0
Performance_schema_statement_classes_lost   0
Performance_schema_table_handles_lost   0
Performance_schema_table_instances_lost 0
Performance_schema_thread_classes_lost  0
Performance_schema_thread_instances_lost    0
Performance_schema_users_lost   0
Prepared_stmt_count 0
Qcache_free_blocks  0
Qcache_free_memory  0
Qcache_hits 0
Qcache_inserts  0
Qcache_lowmem_prunes    0
Qcache_not_cached   0
Qcache_queries_in_cache 0
Qcache_total_blocks 0
Queries 23795485
Questions   23793846
Rows_read   2245200702
Rows_sent   64847900
Rows_tmp_read   723738521
Rpl_status  AUTH_MASTER
Select_full_join    391679
Select_full_range_join  0
Select_range    3458
Select_range_check  0
Select_scan 3722991
Slave_connections   0
Slave_heartbeat_period  0.000
Slave_open_temp_tables  0
Slave_received_heartbeats   0
Slave_retried_transactions  0
Slave_running   OFF
Slave_skipped_errors    0
Slaves_connected    0
Slaves_running  0
Slow_launch_threads 0
Slow_queries    0
Sort_merge_passes   51
Sort_priority_queue_sorts   2232442
Sort_range  2233507
Sort_rows   31535802
Sort_scan   184586
Ssl_accept_renegotiates 0
Ssl_accepts 0
Ssl_callback_cache_hits 0
Ssl_cipher  
Ssl_cipher_list 
Ssl_client_connects 0
Ssl_connect_renegotiates    0
Ssl_ctx_verify_depth    0
Ssl_ctx_verify_mode 0
Ssl_default_timeout 0
Ssl_finished_accepts    0
Ssl_finished_connects   0
Ssl_server_not_after    
Ssl_server_not_before   
Ssl_session_cache_hits  0
Ssl_session_cache_misses    0
Ssl_session_cache_mode  NONE
Ssl_session_cache_overflows 0
Ssl_session_cache_size  0
Ssl_session_cache_timeouts  0
Ssl_sessions_reused 0
Ssl_used_session_cache_entries  0
Ssl_verify_depth    0
Ssl_verify_mode 0
Ssl_version 
Subquery_cache_hit  40610
Subquery_cache_miss 1990420
Syncs   42
Table_locks_immediate   1595095
Table_locks_waited  285
Tc_log_max_pages_used   0
Tc_log_page_size    4096
Tc_log_page_waits   0
Threadpool_idle_threads 0
Threadpool_threads  0
Threads_cached  3
Threads_connected   3
Threads_created 3726
Threads_running 1
Update_scan 736
Uptime  89112
Uptime_since_flush_status   89112
wsrep_cluster_conf_id   18446744073709551615
wsrep_cluster_size  0
wsrep_cluster_state_uuid    
wsrep_cluster_status    Disconnected
wsrep_connected OFF
wsrep_local_bf_aborts   0
wsrep_local_index   18446744073709551615
wsrep_provider_name 
wsrep_provider_vendor   
wsrep_provider_version  
wsrep_ready OFF
wsrep_thread_count  0
```

MySQL TUNER output:

```
General recommendations:
Control warning line(s) into /var/lib/mysql/host.zzz.com.err file
Control error line(s) into /var/lib/mysql/host.zzz.com.err file
Restrict Host for user@% to user@SpecificDNSorIp
MySQL was started within the last 24 hours - recommendations may be inaccurate
Configure your accounts with ip or subnets only, then update your configuration with skip-name-resolve=1
Adjust your join queries to always utilize indexes
Temporary table size is already large - reduce result set size
Reduce your SELECT DISTINCT queries without LIMIT clauses
Consider installing Sys schema from https://github.com/mysql/mysql-sys for MySQL
Consider installing Sys schema from https://github.com/good-dba/mariadb-sys for MariaDB

Variables to adjust:
join_buffer_size (> 256.0K, or always use indexes with JOINs)
innodb_buffer_pool_size (>= 631.3M) if possible.
innodb_log_file_size should be (=64M) if possible, so InnoDB total log files size equals to 25% of buffer pool size.
--
```

Comment: So why did you tag this with "sql-server" when it apparently has nothing to do with Microsoft SQL Server?

Comment: How to mark it for "wrong tag"?

Comment: remove the tag not related  to your db  .. add  a sample of your query and the related  table schema

Comment: `MySQL` and `SQL Server` are completely different products.

Comment: I think the query is too complex to post. it is using various tables, and each table has sometimes up to 100 columns.

Comment: This is a query optimization question that does not include (1) the query, (2) the table definitions of all tables referenced, or (3) the EXPLAIN report for the query. No one can answer this without make pure guesses.

Comment: MysqlTuner checks a few things.  After the 24 hours, please post `SHOW VARIABLES;` and `SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;` and RAM size.  I have a tool that might spot some other things.

Comment: To your question...  The Optimizers for 5.6 and 10.2 have diverged somewhat.  Seeing the query (etc) might make it easier to spot a construct that works better in 5.6, but can be rearranged to work as well or better in 10.2.

Comment: @RickJames I can't post the variable it will exceed 30000 character limit, I posted the Global status. what in queries would you like to know? also, how do I check the RAM? I also posted MYSQL Tuner output.

Comment: @rockyraw - Use post.it or pastbin or ....  Where did the machine come from?  The amount of RAM was surely provided at that time.